# mysql database design for tracking if a user has seen an item

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to show a user only the content he has not viewed yet.
I considered storing a string containing the ids of the items separated by ',' that a user has viewed but i thought i won't know the possible length of the string.
The alternative i could find was to store it like a log. A table like

```
user_id | item_id
1       | 1
2       | 2
1       | 2
```

Which approach will be better for around ten thousand users and thousands of items.

Comment: I strongly vote for the normalized above table you have shown us.  You might think it is inefficient but actually it should make querying relatively easy.  The alternative of storing items in CSV won't scale well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table of pairs like that would be only 10M rows.  That is "medium sized" as tables go.

Have

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id),
INDEX(item_id, user_id)
```

And, if you are not going past 10K and 1K, consider using `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (up to 64K in 2 bytes).  Or, to be more conservative, `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (up to 16M in 3 bytes).

Comment: Unless there is a hard requirement to maintain a lasting history, I'd add a timestamp so I could prune the old data and a cascaded delete foreign key constraint against the item table.